# Rails 5: edit user role on index with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to create view where User can be selected from dropdown and then below Role partial for particular User Role edit is loaded.

This is what I have in */roles/index.html.erb*

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">User name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"><select class="form-control m-b" name="users" id="user_list">
     <option value="">Please, select user</option>
      <% @users.each do |user| %>
       <% for role in user.roles %>
        <option value="<%= role.id %>" data-edit-url="<%= edit_common_role_path(role.id) %>"><%= user.name %></option>
       <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

In */roles_controller.rb* I have this:

```
def index #Here users belonging to current_user is found
 @users = User.joins(:accounts).where("accounts.company_id IN (?)",
          current_user.companies.pluck(:id)).distinct
end

def edit #Each user has its role with user_id column
 @role = Role.find(params[:id])
end
```

I'm new in coding and have read a lot of related blogs, however **I cannot figure out how to do this in single view with dropdown and AJAX?** I would appreciate any help, thank you.

**Update**

This JS can open particular selected User role for Edit:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      edit = $('#user_list').change(function() {
      window.location = $(this).find(":selected").data('edit-url');
     });
</script>
```

**Update 2**

In */roles/index.html.erb* I added partial where role details will be loaded:

```
<div id = selected_role >
  <%= render 'common/roles/editrole' %>
</div>
```

Particular Edit view partial starts with this

```
<%= form_for([:common, @role]) do |f| %>
```

and at the moment I get error: `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`

It seems that the problem is that in index view it tries to render Edit partial looking for some role, however at that moment no User is not selected (role ID is empty). How to fix this, please?

---

**The solution for edit form**

Thanks to @Ahmad hamza & @Jeff I have come to this solution, where I can do Edit action, but still need some final touch for Update action.

In */common/roles/index.erb* I have this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="get" action="/common/roles" data-remote="true">
<div class="col-sm-10"><select class="form-control m-b" name="users" id="user_list">
  <option value="">Please, select user</option>
     <% @users.each do |user| %>
        <% for role in user.roles %>
           <option value="<%= role.id %>"><%= user.name %></option>
        <% end %>
     <% end %>
  </select>
</div>
<!-- Here we render role edit form -->
  <div id = 'selected_role' ></div>
<!-- Role edit form ends -->
```

This is select where User names are displayed, role ID are option value.

In *roles.js* I have listener where on select role ID is passed for Edit:

```
(function($) {
$('#user_list').change(function() {
  var roleId = $( "#user_list" ).val();
  $.ajax({
    url: '/common/roles/' + roleId + '/edit',
    method: 'GET',
  });
});
})(jQuery); /*global jQuery*/
```

*/common/roles/edit.js.erb* looks like this:

```
$("#selected_role").html("<%=j render 'common/roles/editrole', locals: { role: @role } %>");
```

and it renders role edit partial */common/roles/_editrole.html.erb*

```
<%= form_for :role, method: :patch, remote: true do |f| %>
<form class="m-t" role="form" action="" id="editrole">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">General</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10" >
           <%= f.select :general, Role.generals.to_a.map { |w| [w[0].humanize, w[0]] }, {}, {class:"form-control m-b"} %>
            </div>
        </div>
   <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-primary block full-width m-b" %>
  <% end %>
</form>
```

To complete this form I still need to finish with Update action where I have problem. On submitting role edit form it stays in Edit action with this error in console:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PATCH] "/common/roles/1/edit"):
```

although particular route is in place:

```
common_role PATCH  /common/roles/:id(.:format)     common/roles#update
```

In */common/roles_controller.rb* I have this:

```
def update
@role = Role.find(params[:id])
if @role.update_attributes(role_params)
  format.html {
              flash[:success] = "Role updated!"
              redirect_to common_roles_path
  }
  format.js
```

In */common/roles/update.js.erb* I have this line: `$('.editrole').hide()`

**How do I fix this Update action issue, please?**

Comment: If i'm getting it right then when a user gets selected from the drop down then it should load the role of that user. Right?

Comment: Ok, so my suggestion is - figure out how you'd do it without AJAX first (your current form won't do it - it selects a role, not a user)... and then convert it to AJAX once you have your head around that.

Comment: Add an on change javascript listener onto the drop down. Post via ajax to an API that will return the roles of the user in json. Render the json onto the page using jquery.

Comment: @Ahmad hamza Yes, you are right. Visually I show User names, however value is particular User role ID.

Comment: Where do you want to show the user's role ?

Comment: @Jeff Sounds good, but how to implement it? Please, see above in Update my JS for on change.

Comment: @Ahmad hamza I want to show edit partial on same index view where User dropdown select is.

Comment: Ok. Here is a brief tutorial for ajax: https://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2015/3/18/rails-jquery-ajax. Mean while i'll write the solution in the answer.

Comment: @Taryn East Please, see my update above where I have current JS which on change opens role for Edit.

Comment: @Ahmad hamza Yes, that is good tutorial and I have saved it in my links already :) I've even created one small modal window with AJAX, however I'm stuck with this particular dropdown. Thank you for helping.

Comment: I need to understand why are you adding data attribute in the option tag.?

Comment: @Ahmad hamza  Well, so far it seemed to me it allows to open particular role for edit.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you want to show the role of the user when a user gets selected from the drop down.

**Steps**

1. Create a `js` file in the asset folder and include it in the `manifest` file as well(application.js)
2. Trigger a `function` `onChange` of the `dropdown` and use the `id` attribute to get the selected `user` from the drop down.

   ```
   $( ".m-b" ).change(function() {
     var roleId = $( "#user_list" ).val();
   });
   ```
3. Here `ajax` comes into the picture which will help in sending the `role_id` of the selected `user` from the `view` to the `controller` and in return it will return the `object` of the role.

   ```
   $( ".m-b" ).change(function() {
     var roleId = $( "#user_list" ).val();
     $.ajax({
       url: 'roles/' + roleId + '',  #roles edit path
       method: 'GET',
       data: {
         id: roleId;
       }
     });
   });
   ```
4. In the `edit` action of the `roles` controller:

   ```
   def edit
     @role = Role.find(params[:id])
     respond_to do |format|
       format.html
       format.js { @role }  # format.js will identify the ajax request
     end
   end
   ```
5. Add a `div` in the `index` page of `roles` inside of which you will render the details of the found role object.
6. Now you need to update your ajax request method such that it will append the response in the div.

   ```
   $( ".m-b" ).change(function() {
     var roleId = $( "#user_list" ).val();
     $.ajax({
       url: 'roles/' + roleId + '',  #roles edit path
       method: 'GET',
       data: {
         id: roleId;
       }
     })
     .done(function( response ) {
        $('#selected_role').append(response);
     });
   });
   ```

   Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! It looks like I get an error when I add edit view partial. Can you take a look on Update 2 above, please?

Comment: What does it mean to  `format.js { @role }`? Or specifically, does `@role` get passed as a json object? If so, why didnt you just use `format.json { status: 'success', role: @role.to_json }`

Comment: @Jeff Can you take a look on error I'm getting in Update2 above, please? What am I doing wrong in `/roles/index.html.erb`?

Comment: Firstly `<div id = selected_role >` should be `<div id ='selected_role' >`. And in your `edit` action within the controller, you should do `@role ||= Role.new`

Comment: @Jeff Thank you, however it keeps giving me same error + for your suggestion regarding `format.json` it gives syntax error of unexpected ':'

Comment: Try commenting out the partial and see if the page loads. And then try rendering the partial but commenting out the form to pinpoint what is wrong.

Comment: @Jeff I can load page without partial and I can load page with partial where there are no "form_for". It seems like with partial the problem is that partial form is trying to find some role ID, but in Index role ID will be passed when user will be selected from dropdown.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127209/discussion-between-jeff-and-matiss).

Comment: @Jeff  Please, check my latest reply in chat.

Comment: @Jeff, It looks like I've managed to create Edit form with AJAX action, which is awesome :) Thank you for helping! I thought Update action will be easy, however I have some problem there. Can you take a look on my solution post above, please?